# Laravel access request object outside controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

According to the Laravel documentation Request is acquired via dependency injection. For a controller this is fine, but how do we access Request object outside a controller, for example in a view

Comment: Simply, `Request::input('field')`.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH input is not a static method

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is request helper in laravel. You can use Request Object anywhere.
For example

```
request()->field_name
```

Here's  laravel documentation link for request helper
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-request

Comment: This doesn't work in lumen :/ You have to use `app()->request`. Look [Helpers.php](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/6.x/src/helpers.php)

Comment: this is sooooo useful for me to know! `[+1]`

Answer (score 2):

Lumen doesn't have this Helper "request()".

You must use like this:

```
app()->request->field_name
```