# Lumen access Request object outside controller

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am creating a custom guard where I need to access the Request object in order to get http headers. I have tried `request()` but it is undefined in lumen.

How do I get access to Request object outside of an controller class?

**Note:** Not a duplicate of [Laravel access request object outside controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319707/laravel-access-request-object-outside-controller)

Comment: There is no `request` helper in Lumen: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.4/src/helpers.php

Have you tried to use `Illuminate\Http\Request` class?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've never used Lumen myself but you should be able to resolve the current request from the Service Container:

```
app('request');
```

You might have to pass the full class name:

```
app('Illuminate\Http\Request');
```

Or:

```
app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
```