# Get the $request object in Laravel's model events (ex. created, updated etc.)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Eloquent's model events to do some actions after model has been created/updated/deleted. I'm refering to these:

```
class User extends Model 
{

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::created(function($model){
            // ... code here
        });

        self::updated(function($model){
            // ... code here
        });

        self::deleted(function($model){
            // ... code here
        });
    }

}
```

***The question:*** I need to access the $request object in any of these. Is it possible? The scenario I am trying to do is to insert some values in another database table once the current model has been stored. The values are in the $request. And I don't have access to the controller to do it manually there.

Comment: Why do you need to do it here in the event? You can use a transaction and insert into the other table inside that transaction.

Comment: Try `request()`

Comment: You could create a model from the request then assign it to the model statically then you could use in the `boot()` method. This makes the model less coupled with the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can look at:** [Laravel access request object outside controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319707/laravel-access-request-object-outside-controller)

> There is request helper in laravel. You can use Request Object anywhere. For example
>
> ```php
> request()->field_name
> ```